# Calculate Correlation Between Explanatory Variables

Tags: r, regression

We were given an assignment on creating the best regression model, and one of the questions was to calculate the correlation between variables. How do I do that if I have 10 explanatory variables using R.

Thank you

Comment: `cor(df)`. This question is much more likely to receive a useful answer if you show you have put an effort into solving this yourself, and point anything in particular that did not work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

A sample dataset:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=5))
```

[image]

You can easily find the correlation between these variavbles using [cor()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/cor):

```
cor(df)
```

[image]

And you can visualize the relationships using [corrplot()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) like this:

```
corrplot(cor(df), type = "upper", tl.srt = 45)
```

[image]

Here's the whole thing for an easy copy&paste:

```
#install.packages("corrplot")
library("corrplot")

df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=5))
df_cor <- data.frame(cor(df))
corrplot(cor(df), type = "upper", tl.srt = 45)
```

You'll only have to run the first line the very first time.